How did M. Born argued that $|\langle \psi|\phi\rangle|^2$ represents probability of transition from $|\phi\rangle$ to $|\psi\rangle$
In my QFT lecture, we discussed scattering processes and how to find probabilities of transitions.
The initial state is:
$|\phi(t\rightarrow-\infty)\rangle=|i\rangle$. This is the state of the system prior to the scattering event.
We want to find the probability that the system, after scattering is in a certain state $|f\rangle$
Then we write:
$|\langle f |\phi(t\rightarrow-\infty)\rangle|^2=|\langle f|\hat S|i\rangle|^2$ where $\hat S = e^{-i\frac{H}{\hbar}(t-t_0)}$
I was confused initially, regarding the origin of the expression which gives us the probability of transition but then I remembered that this is nothing more than a generalized case of the Born rule, one of the postulates of QM. In my QM we had:
A system is characterized by some measurable physical quantity $\mathcal{A}$ to which an operator $A$ corresponds. For simplicity we consider a discrete basis of kets for the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of the system, comprised of eigenvectors $\{|n\rangle\}$ of $A$. We know that we can express every state as a linear combination of basis kets and we know that the probability of measuring an arbitrary eigenvalue $n$ is:
$P(n)=|\langle n|\psi\rangle|^2$
This probability also represents the probability of the system transitioning from the initial state $|\psi\rangle$ to the final state $|n\rangle$ for whatever reason, in this case because we conducted a measurement, which influences the quantum mechanical system.
This is the Born rule.
My interest is to learn how exactly Born came to the conclusion  that $|\langle f|i\rangle|^2$ corresponds/implies/represents the probability of such transition taking place.
I have searched for this explanation in several books, but it is always said that this is the case, never how he came to this conclusion.
Then I tried myself to give an explanation as to why this is the case and the only explanation I could come up was that, Born introduced the idea, then he or others conducted numerous experiments to prove this statistical claim. But I am not sure, if this is how he came about it or if there is another more intuitive reason. Or perhaps, somewhere there is a proper explanation of his reasoning for saying that  $|\langle f|i\rangle|^2$ represents probability of transition.

In case this is supposed to be specifically a historic question rather than a general question like the duplicates, consider whether it would better fit at [hsm.SE]

I don't think it is supposed to be a historic question. I am not asking about the history as to how Born came up with his rule. I am asking how did he PROVE that considering the square amplitude of the inner product of two states of the system can be interpreted as probability of transition

I am asking how did he PROVE… He didn’t. It’s a postulate.

Helpful link (1) - Wikipedia and two (The original paper, up to translation...)

So qm works on something which wasn't verified ?

@imbAF It is verified to the extent that you can verify such a rule.

"which wasn't verified". How do you think physics works? -- (very very very) roughly: you postulate some structures/axioms whatever, make testable predictions and compare to experiments. --this does not mean that such a "rule" is not debatable. But you have to start to postulate something somewhere.

@TobiasFünke same way Eddington helped with GR. Einstein made a claim and Eddington via experimentation verified that

This is yet another one of those unfortunate consequences of the way the pioneers liked to write. Born rule is very strongly suggested by the analogous problem in classical physics. Indeed, ALL the postulates of QM are extremely well-motivated, and they don't even require a lot of time to explain. But no, we have to have generations of students be confused.
